# Fullcalendar doesn't render in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am trying to display fullcalendar in a modal dialog using bootstrap/jquery.
When the modal appears the calendar doesn't show at first unless the 'Today' button is selected.

I read that I should use:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I recreated the whole problem here.  I used links for my references so you can see the problem if you run this script in Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<!-- IMPORTANT! fullcalendar depends on jquery-ui.min.js for drag & drop support -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<a data-toggle="modal" id="add_appointment" href="#modal_form_addappt" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Add... </a>
    
<!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form_addappt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Appointment...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="calendar"></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<script>
           
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
});
    
$('#modal_form_addappt').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
});
    
</script>
    
</body>
       
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. Change `show.bs.modal` to `shown.bs.modal`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<!-- IMPORTANT! fullcalendar depends on jquery-ui.min.js for drag & drop support -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<a data-toggle="modal" id="add_appointment" href="#modal_form_addappt" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Add... </a>
    
<!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form_addappt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Appointment...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="calendar"></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<script>
           
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
});
    
$('#modal_form_addappt').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
});
    
</script>
    
</body>
       
</html>
```

`show` is called to show the modal, `shown` is called when the modal is shown, so using that allows it to display when the modal is opened.

Comment: You made my day.  I can't thank you enough for catching that!

Comment: Not a problem :) Funny how a single `n` can solve everything!

Comment: Thanks a million buddy. Spent almost 4 hours figuring out why the calendar body is not rendering in Modal!!!